# Scraping one column from table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am trying to scrape last three columns in table for sales from this [website](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_electric_vehicles_in_the_United_States)

I was able to make a script first to show all columns but now i want just last three here i am struggling I used the code below but I am getting errors.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mechanize import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

mech = Browser()
url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_electric_vehicles_in_the_United_States"
soup = BeautifulSoup(mech.open(url))
table = soup.find("table", class_="wikitable")

for row in table('tr')[1:]: print "|".join(col.text.strip() for col in row.find_all('th'))
for row in table('tr')[1:]: print "|".join(col.text.strip() for col in row.find_all('td') if col in row.findAll('th')[0].find('All hybrids sold').text)
```

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrap1.py", line 12, in <module>
    for row in table('tr')[1:]: print "|".join(col.text.strip() for col in row.f
ind_all('td') if col in row.findAll('th')[0].find('All hybrids sold').text)
  File "scrap1.py", line 12, in <genexpr>
    for row in table('tr')[1:]: print "|".join(col.text.strip() for col in row.f
ind_all('td') if col in row.findAll('th')[0].find('All hybrids sold').text)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What errors are you getting specifically?

Comment: @Cyber I updated with error.

Comment: IMHO, the markup is much, much more complicated than the code above can actually handle, especially with the last three columns.